# Problem while accessing active directory using C# DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

```
  string ldapPath = "ldap://db.debian.org:389/uid=ma,ou=users,dc=debian,dc=org";
            DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);

            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);

            search.Filter = "((objectClass=*))";
            search.FindAll();
```

I am using the above code from my C# forms application. Whenever i am calling the FindAll() I am getting an exception as below.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
>   Message="Unknown error (0x80005000)"
>   Source="System.DirectoryServices"   ErrorCode=-2147463168
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean
>   throwIfFail)
>          at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
>          at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
>          at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean
>   findMoreThanOne)
>          at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll()
>          at LDAPApp.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   H:\Raj\LDAP\LDAPApp\LDAPApp\Form1.cs:line 37
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m,
>   MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at LDAPApp.Program.Main() in
>   H:\Raj\LDAP\LDAPApp\LDAPApp\Program.cs:line 18
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly,
>   String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:

Please tell me what am i doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not exactly apply to your case, but in my case I encountered this error when I had a trailing "/" and did not need to include a distinguished name. Ex: LDAP://db.debian.org:389 works but LDAP://db.debian.org:389/ exceptions with ErrorCode -2147463168.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LDAP protocol identifier (LDAP://) in your LDAP path must be uppercase.
If you write the LDAP protocol identifier in lowercase you get the 0x80005000 error
code (unknown error). The following code snippet should work:

```
string ldapPath = "LDAP://db.debian.org:389/uid=ma,ou=users,dc=debian,dc=org";
        DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, null, null,  AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);

search.Filter = "((objectClass=*))";
search.FindAll();
```

Hope, this helps.